# trouble with table borders - some are incomplete

Tags: tables

I am having trouble with my table borders again. I want to produce something like this: 
[image]

or like this:
[image]

But I keep getting this:
[image]

These are my commands:

```
    \begin{table}[ht!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\small
\doublespacing
\begin{center}
    \caption{The Estimated Effect of Cultural Distance on Protectionism, Treatment Received}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Treatment Received}}\\ \cline{2-3}
    & All Respondents & Prejudiced Respondents\\ \cline{1-3}
    Culturally Foreign & 25.6 & 44.4\\ 
    Culturally Familiar & 20.0 & 19.0\\
    Difference & 5.6 & 25.4*\\
    (95\% Confidence Interval) & (-1.1 to 12.4) & (6.6 to 44.1)\\
    p-value & 0.101  & 0.009\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{c}` should be `\multicolumn{2}{c|}` as you want a rule after the span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\small
\doublespacing
\begin{center}
\caption{The Estimated Effect of Cultural Distance on Protectionism, Treatment Received}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Treatment Received}}\\ \cline{2-3}
& All Respondents & Prejudiced Respondents\\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Culturally Foreign} & 25.6 & 44.4\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Culturally Familiar} & 20.0 & 19.0\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Difference} & 5.6 & 25.4*\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(95\% Confidence Interval)} & (-1.1 to 12.4) & (6.6 to 44.1)\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{p-value} & 0.101  & 0.009\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You may want to replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and omit the `\end{center}` instruction. Doing so will avoid the insertion of unwanted (vertical) whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution and a different look might be of interest: the last two columns have equal (minimal) width and the data are centred.

```
        \documentclass{scrartcl}%

        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{setspace}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \newlength{\colwidth}
        \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
        \usepackage{colortbl}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{table}[ht!]
        \doublespacing\centering
        \small\arrayrulecolor{SteelBlue}\arrayrulewidth = 1.2pt
        \settowidth{\colwidth}{Prejudiced Respondents}
        \caption{The Estimated Effect of Cultural Distance on Protectionism, Treatment Received}
        \begin{tabular}{r@{\color{SteelBlue}\enspace\vrule width 2pt\enspace}c @{\color{SteelBlue}\vrule width 1.2pt\ }c @{\color{SteelBlue}\vrule width 1.2pt}c}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Treatment Received}} & \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c@{\color{SteelBlue}\enspace\vrule width 2pt\enspace}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[\colwidth][c]{All Respondents}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Prejudiced Respondents}\\
        \cline{2-4}\\[-12pt]%{1.2pt}
        Culturally Foreign & 25.6 & 44.4\\
        Culturally Familiar & 20.0 & 19.0\\
        Difference & 5.6 & 25.4*\\
        (95\% Confidence Interval) & (-1.1 to 12.4) & (6.6 to 44.1)\\
        p-value & 0.101  & 0.009\\[6pt]% \cline{2-3}
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

        \begin{table}[ht!]
        \doublespacing\centering
        \small\arrayrulecolor{SteelBlue}\arrayrulewidth = 2pt
        \settowidth{\colwidth}{Prejudiced Respondents}
        \caption{The Estimated Effect of Cultural Distance on Protectionism, Treatment Received}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\color{SteelBlue}\enspace\vrule width 2pt\enspace}c @{\color{SteelBlue}\vrule width 1.2pt\ }c @{\color{SteelBlue}\vrule width 1.2pt}c}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Treatment Received}} &\\
        \multicolumn{1}{c@{\color{SteelBlue}\enspace\vrule width 2pt\enspace}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[\colwidth][c]{All Respondents}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Prejudiced Respondents}\\
        \hline\\[-12pt]%{1.2pt}{2-4}
        Culturally Foreign & 25.6 & 44.4\\
        Culturally Familiar & 20.0 & 19.0\\
        Difference & 5.6 & 25.4*\\
        (95\% Confidence Interval) & (-1.1 to 12.4) & (6.6 to 44.1)\\
        p-value & 0.101  & 0.009\\[6pt]% \cline{2-3}
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]